# Android 11 for react native?

Tags: android, react-native

I have added a Git link below for some context, specially ggerminiani's answer.

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/530

Apparently I need Android 11 for Stripe react-native SDK to work, but I have no idea how to upgrade to Android 11, I have never used Android Studio either.

This is how my build files look

android/build.gradle

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21 //was 16
        compileSdkVersion =29 //was 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29  //was 29

        

        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "18.0.0" // <--- use this version or newer
        /*androidXAnnotation = "1.2.0"
        androidXBrowser = "1.3.0"*/
    }
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sofood"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

First download the latest version of Android Studio from
https://developer.android.com/studio

Then, update the sdk version:

```
compileSdkVersion = 30 // update to 30
targetSdkVersion = 30 // update to 30
```